# Find and replace - simple bash script

Tags: linux, bash, filter

I am not really familiar to bash scripting, but suppose I have a file `textfile.txt` with names and mails consisting of several lines with several numbers of occurences of these patterns :

```
name@surname.net;othername.othersurname;name@surname.net;othername.othersurname;name@surname.net;...
```

I would like to suppress from this list all the entries that are not mails. So suppose that my executable file is file.sh and that I run sh file.sh textfile.txt

```
#!/bin/bash

if [–f $1];

awk -F ";" '{//here comes what I am looking for
}' $1

else 

echo "there is no such file"

fi
```

I don't know with which syntax I can grab the last filtered entry ( to check if there isn't an `@` sign to delete it from the list). I tried to google it but with no success

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do: edit the file in place, removing all the non-email-addresses? Display all the email addresses in the file? Something else?

Comment: Yes exactly, I am trying to edit the file in place, removing all the non-email-addresses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do it in a bash script without awk or perl ...

```
origfile=$1
copyfile=`mktemp`

for email in `sed 's/;/\n/g' $origfile | grep "@"`; do
    printf "$email;" >> $copyfile
done

#you may want to check that $copyfile is valid in some way before the next step
mv $copyfile $origfile
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know `awk` sorry, but you can do it with perl

```
perl -p -e 's/;[^;@]+;/;/g'
```

But this has one bug in it, it will miss it if the first or last entry in the line is the invalid email. To solve these properly you need the split/check/join which starts to get messy as a single line

```
perl -p -e 'join(";",grep(/@/,split(";",$_)))'
```

Edit: Oops, sorry, mistake when cutting over from ideone to command line. I was missing the assignment back to `$_`, which is what is printed by the `-p`

```
perl -p -e '$_ = join(";",grep(/@/,split(";",$_)))'
```

- `split(";",$_)` splits the current line (`$_`) into an array of elements using the `;` as the delimiter.
- `grep(/@/,...)` then only returns the elements of the array which contain an `@`. This was my simplistic test for a valid email address. If you want to be more thourough you could use a more rigorous regexp for email address. Maybe `/^[^\s@]+@[^\s@]+\.[^\s@]+$/`
- Then the `join(";"...)` recombines the valid email addresses into a `;` delimited string.

Comment: btw could you explain how this syntax means : grep(/@/,split(";",$_))

Answer (score 0):

Here an `awk` solution. But only `awk`, so I don't suggest to include it inside a shell script. It should work running it from the command line:

```
awk '

    ## Split (in input) and join (in output) fields with colon.
    BEGIN { FS = OFS = ";" }
    {   
        ## Traverse all fields and delete those that do not contain one "@".
        for ( i = 1; i <= NF; i++ ) { if ( index( $i, "@" ) == 0 ) { $i = "" } } 

        ## There will be some consecutive colons between those fields deleted.
        ## Keep only one.
        gsub( /;{2,}/, ";" )

        ## Print the whole line only with emails.
        print
    }   

' infile
```

With your example line, it gives:

```
name@surname.net;name@surname.net;name@surname.net
```